DataColumn.Expression SUBSTRING(expression, start, length)
I am importing values from a file (provided to me and I can't change the file's original format) to a DataTable and one of the columns is a location column and unfortunately it contains both the latitude and longitude values, which requires me to split them.
    DataTable table = new DataTable ();

    // Create the first column.
    DataColumn locationColumn = new DataColumn();
    locationColumn.ColumnName = "Location (Lat, Long)";

    // Create the second, calculated, column.
    DataColumn latColumn = new DataColumn();
    latColumn.ColumnName = "Latitude";
    latColumn.Expression = "SUBSTRING([Location (Lat, Long)],1,5)";

    // Create third column.
    DataColumn longColumn = new DataColumn();
    longColumn.ColumnName = "Longitude";
    longColumn.Expression = "SUBSTRING([Location (Lat, Long)],8,5)";

The location column has a mixture of values because trailing zeros are not included to pad out to a fixed width:

"40.12, -60.12"
"40.12345, -60.12345"

From the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-data-datacolumn-expression):
SUBSTRING(expression, start, length)
So, the above expression doesn't correctly split the values because of the fixed start and length positions.
There's no reference in the documentation to a FIND(",") or INDEXOF(",") type functions so I'm hoping someone knows if there is a way to do what I'm after? Or am I stuck needing to iterate the rows and use c# to split and allocate the values to the respective columns?
